# Selecting only the closest value using LEFT JOIN and ON statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue on how to do this using LEFTJOIN. Is there a way for `LEFT JOIN` and `ON` to specifically pick only the **closest value** in the query where it will be `LEFT JOIN`?

Example, I have values from a query like this table below that is sorted based on checkdate, and I sorted the value based on **2019-12-25**. I only want to select the value closest to **2019-12-25 14:50:00.000** so, technically the only value that should be used is **2019-12-25 14:51:57.000** since it is the nearest, how do we do this using `LEFT JOIN`?

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| badgenumber | checktype | recordout               | checkdate  |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:00:02.000 | 2019-12-25 | 
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:39:57.000 | 2019-12-25 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:51:57.000 | 2019-12-25 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 22:41:57.000 | 2019-12-25 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 22:52:57.000 | 2019-12-25 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
```

This is the query that I'm working on, the `employeeidno, fullname, departmentname` are hidden.

Values are used are as follows.

- t0.noofhoursduty = 8
- t0.mergetimeoutorig = 2019-12-25 14:50:00.000

This is the query including `LEFT JOIN`.

```
LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    MAX(userinfo.badgenumber) AS badgenumber, 
    MAX(RTRIM(checkinout.checktype)) AS 'checktype', 
    MAX(checkinout.checktime) as 'recordout', 
    MAX(CONVERT(date,checkinout.checktime)) as checkdate, 
    MAX(RTRIM(employeemasterfile.employeeidno)) AS 'employeeidno', 
    MAX(RTRIM(employeemasterfile.lastname))+', '+ 
    MAX(RTRIM(employeemasterfile.firstname))+' '+ MAX(LEFT(employeemasterfile.middlename,1))+'.' AS 'fullname', 
    MAX(RTRIM(departmentmasterfile.departmentname)) AS 'departmentname' 
FROM ((checkinout INNER JOIN userinfo 
    ON checkinout.userid = userinfo.userid) 
INNER JOIN employeemasterfile 
    ON userinfo.badgenumber = employeemasterfile.fingerscanno) 
INNER JOIN departmentmasterfile 
    ON LEFT(employeemasterfile.employeeidno, 4) = LEFT(departmentmasterfile.departmentcode, 4) 
WHERE 
CONVERT(date,checkinout.checktime) BETWEEN '2019-12-21' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,'2020-01-05') 
    AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'O' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
GROUP BY 
    userinfo.badgenumber, LEFT(checkinout.checktime,14)) AS t2
ON 
    t2.recordout BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-(t0.noofhoursduty/2),t0.mergetimeoutorig) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1,t0.mergetimeoutorig)
    AND t2.badgenumber = t0.fingerscanno
    AND t0.schedulename !='REST'
```

This will be the output of the query above. Same date result is okay because there are instances that a person logs in 4x in a day in different timestamps. Or a person has 2 or more schedule within the day.

```
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | badgenumber | checktype | recordout               | checkdate  | employeeidno | fullname | departmentname |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-21 23:43:36.000 | 2019-12-21 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-22 22:36:50.000 | 2019-12-22 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-23 18:03:16.000 | 2019-12-23 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-24 22:06:58.000 | 2019-12-24 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:00:02.000 | 2019-12-25 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:39:57.000 | 2019-12-25 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 14:51:57.000 | 2019-12-25 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 22:41:57.000 | 2019-12-25 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-25 22:52:57.000 | 2019-12-25 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-26 14:00:02.000 | 2019-12-26 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-28 22:00:01.000 | 2019-12-28 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-28 23:31:11.000 | 2019-12-28 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-29 15:08:10.000 | 2019-12-29 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2019-12-30 16:03:20.000 | 2019-12-30 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2020-01-02 06:52:18.000 | 2020-01-02 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2020-01-03 08:00:57.000 | 2020-01-03 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
    | 1233        | O         | 2020-01-04 06:40:11.000 | 2020-01-04 | ------------ | -------- | -------------- |
    +-------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
```

What I currently got right now seems to work, but when there are large differences in timestamp, the data becomes duplicated, example, if the person timestamps 'O' (checktype) In around **12AM - 9AM** and pressed again at around **10AM - 7PM**, the record will show 2 data within the same date, and that's okay, my main problem is how do we select only the nearest value compared to it in `LEFT JOIN`?

To summarize, will there be a way for `LEFT JOIN` to only select the closest value based on recordout, if I'm going to use **2019-12-25 14:50:00.000** as a basis for LEFT JOIN, then only **2019-12-25 14:51:57.000** should be selected for LEFT JOIN. I tried using `BETWEEN` and `DATEADD(-+HOUR)`, but it is still selecting all the data within the same recordout. Is there a way to do this? or this is plausible using only `LEFT JOIN`?

Is there a way to modify these line of codes to reach my goal?

```
ON 
    t2.recordout BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-(t0.noofhoursduty/2),t0.mergetimeoutorig) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1,t0.mergetimeoutorig)
    AND t2.badgenumber = t0.fingerscanno
    AND t0.schedulename !='REST'
```

Hoping for a positive response, this has been bugging me for a long time on how to do this using LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Either add an outer SELECT to detect and eliminate doubles or use OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT JOIN and select first matching row using proper ordering.

Comment: @Serg May I ask for as simple working sample? I'll try to use it to my database. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT JOIN and select only the first matching row using proper order by, something like that:

```
...
OUTER APPLY (
 select top(1) *
 from (
        SELECT 
        MAX(userinfo.badgenumber) AS badgenumber, 
        -- you current t2 subquery
      ) AS t2
 where 
    t2.recordout BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-(t0.noofhoursduty/2),t0.mergetimeoutorig) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1,t0.mergetimeoutorig)
    AND t2.badgenumber = t0.fingerscanno
    AND t0.schedulename !='REST'
 order by abs(datediff(minute, t0.mergetimeoutorig, t2.recordout )) desc
) t2
```

This is hardly working query as I see no sample data and no table structures but hopefully it helps to get to the right direction.

Comment: Brother, I used the logic behind your query structure and implemented it in my entire query and it worked, I can't thank you enough for this, you just saved me a month of studying. I'm going to check on how ````OUTER APPLY```` works and implement this on my other scripts. Thank you so much!